# Oauth Middleware LDAP authenication

Tags: active-directory, oauth-2.0, middleware

What I have is a bunch of users who all have their credentials stored in active directory.   Currently I use a custom LDAP method to verify the users name and password but I was wondering how can I incorporate this method with OAuth to support webservices?

I realize that OAuth is "authorization" but now I need the authentication piece.   Azure AD just isn't an option on the budget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you could not use [OpenID Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openid-connect) for your purposes. As you mentioned OAuth is for Authorization (well really, delegation). OpenID Connect is built on OAuth to add Authentication abilities to OAuth.

Your Authorization Server would interact with Microsoft Active Directory and your OAuth Clients would then interact with the Authorization Server va Microsoft Active Directory.

Many third-party Access Manager products make this type or interaction very easy. Or, if you trust your security skills there are [libraries for OWIN](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473126)  if you are using (.NET etc) and other [OpenID Connect Libraries](https://openid.net/developers/libraries/) available and several "middleware" servers support OpenID Connect out-of-the-box.

-jim